# "A present-tense record"

Tags: meaning

> ***A present-tense** record of nation-splitting turmoil, Patricio Guzmán’s monumental documentary *[The Battle of Chile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Battle_of_Chile)* remains a landmark of activist cinema.*

http://www.slantmagazine.com/film/review/the-battle-of-chile

I am at a loss how to translate meaningfully the phrase "present-tense" given the context of the sentence. Initially I thought that I can paraphrase it as "A record that presents account on tense events that occured in Chile…". But I am not sure at all now. Can you tell me the exact meaning of the phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the ***present-tense*** in *A present-tense record* refers to the "narrative present", also commonly known as **[historical present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present)**, which "refers to the employment of the present tense when narrating past events.

The historical present will give the audience "a sense of immediacy, as of a recurring vision", so CopperKettle's suggestion that the film would give the feeling of the "present" is not very far off. In fact, I believe that the film used everything to achieve the effect of the "present".

I've checked it on IMDb. According to IMDb, [The Battle of Chile: Part I (1975)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072685/)'s language is Spanish. I can't say anything much about Spanish, but according to [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2002/sep/14/books.featuresreviews), the film appeared to be voiced over in English in the present tense (i.e. the historical present):

> Everything about the style of the film - the restless camera, the short scenes, the present-tense voiceover - indicates that its makers suspected this as well.

which sums up the whole sense of "A present-tense record" quite well.

Comment: I was just too lazy to reformulate.. (0:

Comment: I think your answer (now deleted) is good too, if you added the historical present to it, it would be perfect. :-)

Comment: I'm busy with logarithmic equations.. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

The [present tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_tense) is used to describe actions happening in the present time. Describing the documentary as 'present-tense' suggests that it was made at the time of the events it describes (rather than being made later, as many documentaries are).

The reviewer probably regards this as a good thing - that the sense of immediacy resulting from it makes the documentary better at conveying to the viewer what it was like to be there when the events it depicts happened.